# How to detect that an app is shutdown vs. suspended

Tags: android, ios, uno-platform

How could I detect that an app really is shutdown/killed vs. being suspended (.Suspending/.Suspended)?

I needed to trigger some code only as the app ultimately is killed (if ever).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Application.Suspending` event (e.g. [on iOS](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/34fbc75998593fc9f5018fb3775a0e2b2176d0d3/src/Uno.UI/UI/Xaml/Application.iOS.cs#L120)) is raised when the application is being suspended.

You generally cannot determine reliably if the app is being killed, and can only do something when the app restarts, during the `OnLaunched` method. You should assume that your app may be terminated once `Suspending` has been invoked.

Comment: Thanks @Jerome

Here is the problem: we do have a WebSocket connection which should stay connected even as the app 'is pushed to the background' (which raises .Suspending), but should be properly shut down as the app is killed.

Do you guys have any experience e.g. with destructor on a static (dummy) instance being called as the app is killed (vs. .Suspending being called) which then could be used to properly shut down the WebSocket?

Any other idea for a work around would be appreciated as well...

Comment: Mobile apps can't behave this way, and cannot have an active background connection because of battery constraints. In most cases, the architecture for such concerns is done through "raw" or live push notifications, so the user can get back into the app as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Called when app is being killed:

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Called when app is being paused:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Is this 'Platform UNO' = C#?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The code I provided should be in your MainActivity class.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're on the same track: I was referring to the  Windows.UI.Xaml.Application C# class which is supported via Platform UNO on iOS and Android. There is a .Suspending and a .Suspended event. 

In that context there is no MainActivity class AFAIK